# Prayers while traveling between multiple destinations

Tags: salat-al-qasr

I am traveling in the following sequence, is qasr applicable?

I live in city A.
I travel for 2 days and reach city B.
I stay in B for 2 days.
I travel for more than 1 day and reach city C.
I stay in C for 15 days.
I travel for 2 days back to A.

Distance between A & B and B & C and A & C is a few hundred miles. I am away from home for a 100s of miles during the whole journey.
I am not returning to my home A at any point during the journey.

Comment: The majority requires a distance for traveling for qasr being permissible. Further it is important to know that traveling means that one wouldn't stay the night at home so even if you traveled the minimum distance but were able to return home qasr isn't applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two conditions for Salat-ul-Qasr:

1. **Distance** from home/town
2. **Duration** of journey

Regarding **distance**, there are several different opinions about the minimum distance one should travel for Qasr. It varies from ~40-121 kilometers. Another opinion is that one will be a *musafir* when they have travelled three manzils (or three days of traveling), each manzil being 16 miles and total of 48 miles (~77 kilometers).

Regarding **duration**, there is agreement that your traveling must be for 15 days or less to a single place.

- If you stay more than 15 days there, then you should not offer Qasr.
- If your plan was to stay less than 15 days, but you overstayed, then  you should offer Qasr until you 15 days and full Salah after 15 days.
- If your plan was to stay less than 15 days, but your stay gets prolonged and you are hoping to return in next 1-2 days, then you will continue to offer Qasr, regardless of how long you stay. In this scenario, you were planning to return but could not because of the uncertainty of your plan.
- You will offer full Salah only if you intend to stay more than 15 days. If you return before 15 days, then you offered full Salah because your plan was for over 15 days.
- If you travel to one place for less than 15 days and offered Qasr, but then travelled to another place far, the 15 days counter will restart. Even if you do this for multiple cities, even for months, you will continue to offer Qasr, as long as you did not stay over 15 days at any one place.

When will Salat-ul-Qasr **start**?

- One opinion is that a person becomes musafir as soon as he leaves his locality (boundary of town/city etc.).
- Other opinion is that a person becomes musafir only after traveling the minimum distance required.

---

More reading:

[Source 1](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/36063/prayer-while-traveling-qasr-salah-and-its-conditions/)
[Source 2](https://myislam.org/shortening-the-salah-while-travelling/)
[Source 3](https://www.al-islam.org/prayer-salat-according-five-islamic-schools-law-muhammad-jawad-mughniyya/salat-during-travel-salat)